# TeX evaluates 'document' code in preamble

Tags: programming

I have the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.30 \AddDemo{text}{Sample Text}
```

in the following code

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\makeatletter

\providecommand\AddDemo[2]{%
  % #1 : package/identifier
  % #2 : content
  \providecommand{\demo@content@#1}{#2}%
}

\AddDemo{text}{Sample Text}%
\makeatother
\listfiles

\begin{document}
%\PrintDemo{text}
\end{document}
```

which I do not understand.

Basically I want to save (large) text parts which shall be printed on request as a combination of latex and listings.

Comment: You must use `\expandafter\providecommand\csname demo@content@#1\endcsname{#2}` . You can also use the provided commands of etoolbox. See: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=csname

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how TeX constructs macro names. In the code

```
\providecommand\AddDemo[2]{%
  % #1 : package/identifier
  % #2 : content
  \providecommand{\demo@content@#1}{#2}%
}
```

TeX sees a macro `\demo@content@` followed by the text supplied as `#1`. As a result, the later is placed in the input stream, and you see the error about text in the preamble. You need to use `\csname` to construct the macro name:

```
\providecommand\AddDemo[2]{%
  % #1 : package/identifier
  % #2 : content
  \expandafter\providecommand\csname demo@content@#1\endcsname{#2}%
}
```

You need the `\expandafter` here so that the `\csname` is constructed before `\providecommand` is 'executed'.

Comment: Thank you. However now a similar problem exists on printing the value:

    `\providecommand\PrintDemo[1]{%
      \ifcsdef{\demo@content@#1}%
      { % print 
        \demo@content@#1%
      }%
      { % error if not defined
        \PackageError{\packagename}%
         {%
            \MessageBreak
            no demo for '#1' defined \MessageBreak
         }{}
         \endinput%
      }
    }`

this results always in '! Undefined control sequence.'

    `\expandafter\csname demo@content@#1\endcsname`

does not help here

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech `etoolbox` has a number of tools for checking by csname, for example `\ifcsdef` (which 'partners' `\ifdef`).

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech You need to use a csname for `\ifcsdef`, so something like `\ifcsdef{demo@content@#1}` (notice the lack of a `\ `). A _csname_ does not have a leading `\ `, whereas a _control sequence_ does.

Comment: (Internally `\ifcsdef` creates a control sequence from its csname argument, whereas `\ifdef` needs a control sequence argument.)

Answer (score 4):

```
\expandafter\providecommand\csname demo@content@#1\endcsname{#2}
```

You can't append letters to a control sequence name that way, because `\demo@content@` is already a token by itself.

Comment: About 44 seconds faster than me, but I typed more :-)